# CSS Animation resets during execution

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using webkit keyframes to animate some rectangles.  From everything  I can see, the animation should be operating correctly.  I'm using the `forwards` modifier to retain animation changes and all of my syntax is correct **(see my CSS below)**.  However, every time I execute, the animation seems to drop each of the animation changes as they occur.

So for example, say I modify the width of the rectangle at 0% and then rotate the rectangle at 25%.  As it is rotating, the width will return to its original setting.  I'm really not sure what's happening here.  Am I missing a fundamental aspect to keyframes?

```
.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(1) {
    opacity: 100;
    -webkit-animation: close-top 5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes close-top {
    0% {transform: translate(0px, 5px);}
    33% {transform: translate(0px, 15px);}
    66% {transform: scaleX(0.5);}
    100% {transform: rotate(-45deg);}
}
```

Comment: You might need to concatenate transformations: `100% {transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, 15px);}`

Comment: Will concatenation get rid of the distinctions between the transformations?  I need each transformation to be noticeable not blurred together

Answer (score 2):

every step is override the previous step property transform, what you can do is to append to this property the previous changes, like this:

```css
.navbar-toggler:not(.collapsed) .icon-bar:nth-child(1) {
    opacity: 100;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: close-top 5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes close-top {
    0% {transform: translate(0px, 5px);}
    33% {transform: translate(0px, 15px);}
    66% {transform: translate(0px, 15px) scaleX(0.5);}
    100% {transform: translate(0px, 15px) scaleX(0.5) rotate(-45deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class='navbar-toggler'>
  <div class='icon-bar'>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how the `transform` property works. Every time you are setting `transform` in your keyframes you are overwriting the previous value.

What you want is something like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes close-top {
    0% {transform: translate(0px, 5px);}
    33% {transform: translate(0px, 15px);}
    66% {transform:  scaleX(0.5) translate(0px, 15px) ;}
    100% {transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(0.5) translate(0px, 15px);}
}
```

Note how I am keeping the previous transforms present in the value and adding the new change to the front of of the list.

The the individual transforms evaluate from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

All the stages of the animation are `transform` settings – if a new one is triggered, it replaces the previous one (the previous parameters are animated back to their default values). To avoid that, leave the previous values/parameters in the new transform setting and add the new parameter/setting as shown below:

```css
.test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #fa0;
  -webkit-animation: close-top 5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes close-top {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  }
  33% {
    transform: translate(0px, 15px);
  }
  66% {
    transform: translate(0px, 15px) scaleX(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, 15px) scaleX(0.5) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```